# Do all inventors need to fill in an aia0081 to nominate a single inventor as having power of attorney?

Tags: pro-se, aia0081

If I'm filing a patent application with one or more co-inventors, and I'm going to be the one prosecuting it pro se, the rest of the inventors need to fill in an aia0081 form to assign power of attorney to me.

Do I need to file an aia0081 form for myself as well, ceding power of attorney to myself? Logically, I'd think the answer is "no", but logic doesn't always give you the right answer when it comes to the law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems logical to assume that you would be ok with yourself having power of attorney but when it comes to the USPTO I would be safe and sign it.

--George

Comment: Fair point. I took your advice to play it safe, and I did file a power of attorney assignment, assigning it from myself to myself. It didn't raise any questions and was accepted.